# Хранение картинок и прочих ресурсов внутри программы

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм

Есть у меня некоторая программа, которая использует некоторое количество картинок. Я хочу по возможности все эти картинки убрать внутрь программы, чтобы программа представляла собой один исполняемый файл.
По поводу реализации. Я планирую это сделать путем кодирования всех этих файлов ресурсов в base64 и захардкоживания получившихся строк в программе. 
Как такой подход скажется на программе (помимо увеличения исполняемого файла)? Какие его минусы и какие есть альтернативы?

---

**Upd1.** Картинок и прочих ресурсов может быть немало - десятки или даже несколько сотен (т.е. это не единичный случай, как, например, с курсором). Графическая система не очень важна (любая, которая умеет принять картинку из файла/строки данных). Пока стоит некая абстрактная задача понять способы, как можно сложить все статические файлы ресурсов в один исполняемый файл с программой.

Comment: Для разных систем существует компиляторы ресурсов. Имхо, есть смысл использовать готовые, а не изобретать свои.

Comment: zlib вместо base64 тогда уж. Наверняка объем будет меньше, чем у исходных данных.

Comment: Из минусов - base64 будет больше по размеру, чем если бы вы оригинальные картинки в ресурсы положили. Другой минус - вам придется их декодировать, что, в зависимости от кол-ва/размера картинок, замедлит программу.

Comment: Если на первом этапе распаковать и при выполнении программы уже хранить изображение, то скажится только на скорости открытия программы, а потом все ресурсы распакованы и в памяти.

Comment: base64 не нужен, поскольку в с с++ можно хранить данные бинарником. Просто обьявляете unsigned char obj1[] = { 0x10, 0x20} и храните себе в сегменте данных. В windows можно хранить в сегменте ресурсов. Так же через __emit__ можно хранить данные в сегменте кода. В другие сегменты запхать данные можно на ассемблере + метки в линкер.

Comment: Уточните картинки зачем нужны - это иконки, курсоры или просто некие изображения, которые подкладываются на основную форму окна? И какую среду и библиотеку граф. элементов используете - Builder, MSVS  etc. + MFC, Qt, VCL etc. или что-то другое?

Comment: @gecube, обновил вопрос

Answer (score 3):

Собственно, у программы есть секция ресурсов, и в нее можно помещать любые бинарные данные. Полагаю, этим и следует воспользоваться.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте графический редактор [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/). В нём есть возможность сохранения RGB и RGBA картинки в виде C-файла содержащего массив char по 2 -- 4 байта на пиксел построчно.